# MongoDB: on same document using result from query in same query

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am trying to form a query with following document in mongo db:

```
myMetaDataDoc document
{
  _id: <objectId>,
  tour: 
  {
    tourId: "TOURID1",
    stops: [{
      locationId: "LOC1",
      stopId: "STOPID1",
      ...
    ],[
      locationId: "LOC2",
      stopId: "STOPID2",
    ]}
  }
  schedule:{
    stopSchedules: [{
      stopId: "STOPID1"
      ...
    },{
      stopId: "STOPID2"
      ...
    }]
  }
}
```

Basically I want to get all the stops with their respective schedule information in one location.  I require a single query to achieve following:

1. query all stops with location (eg. LOC1)
2. query all stopSchedules having stops.stopId from 1.
3. return stops + schedules

What I tried was using aggregate, but couldn't get the stops.stopId to be used in the same query. This was my attempt:

```
db.myMetaDataDoc.aggregate([
 {$match : {'tour.stops.locationId':'LOC1'}},    // all tour stops with locationId as LOC1
 {$unwind : '$tour.stops'},  // break all stops
 {$match : {'tour.stops.locationId':'LOC1'} },  // all tour with only stops with locationId as LOC1
 {$unwind : '$schedule.stopSchedules'}, // break all stopschedules
 {$match : {'schedule.stopSchedules.stopsId' : {$in :<stopId array>}} }  // missing array of stopId
])
```

removing last $match, I receive all rows with single "tour.stops" and single "schedules.stopSchedules".

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xx1"), "myMetaDataDoc" : {"tour" : { "tourId" : "TOURID1", "stops" : { "locationId" : "LOC1", "stopId" : "STOPID1"} } , "schedule" : { "stopSchedules" : { "stopId" : "STOPID1", ...}}}}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xx2"), "myMetaDataDoc" : {"tour" : { "tourId" : "TOURID1", "stops" : { "locationId" : "LOC1", "stopId" : "STOPID1"} } , "schedule" : { "stopSchedules" : { "stopId" : "STOPID2", ...}}}}
```

From these set of rows I only need those where stops.stopId equals schedules.stopSchedules.stopId. It seems aggregate does not like $where. Should I be using mapreduce() instead? or a server-side script?

Appreciate all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After trying out a bit with aggregate and $eq operator I think I got something close to what I needed. What I did was to skip the last match and use group on all rows with a valid field using $eq operator. I later remove it using projection.

```
db.myMetaDataDoc.aggregate([
 {$match : {'tour.stops.locationId':'LOC1'}},    // all tour stops with locationId as LOC1
 {$unwind : '$tour.stops'},  // break all stops
 {$match : {'tour.stops.locationId':'LOC1'} },  // all tour with only stops with locationId as LOC1
 {$unwind : '$schedule.stopSchedules'}, // break all stopschedules
 {$group : { 
    '_id': '$tour.tourId', 
    valid: {$first: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$tour.stops.stopId','$schedule.stopSchedules.stopId']}, '1', '0']}},    // validate row 
    stop : { $first: '$tour.stops'}, 
    schedule : {$first: '$schedule.stopSchedules'}
 {$match : {'valid':'1'} },    // skip invalid rows
 {
    $project: {            // remove valid field
        _id: 1,
        stop: 1,
        schedule:1
    }
 }
])
```

I am still open for a better solution.